# Django-PayPal IPN urls include not working

Tags: python, django, paypal, django-paypal

I was following the instructions [here](https://django-paypal.readthedocs.org/en/stable/standard/ipn.html) to use PayPal standard IPN. I got stuck at step 4 where I have to include the 'paypal.standard.ipn.urls'.
When I visit my localhost it shows 
**NameError at / 

name 'include' is not defined.** 

The error might not be django specific but I really need help. I know there are some similar questions but none of them seems to have a problem on this particular step. Thank you!

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^notify/', include('paypal.standard.ipn.urls')),
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import `include`:

```
from django.conf.urls import include
```